# how to work with and draw resize images WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resize, draw

Hello I need to know how I can manage to resize and draw pictures in a given space and the top and left values ​​are stored in a database or XML. What elements need to use?

I put pictures of the software that works to perfection, really need to create something like what is shown in the following images:

[Imagen 2](http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/2935/sinttulo2ol.jpg)

[Imagen 3](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/7119/sinttulo3mb.jpg)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a canvas with a resizing adorner that tells the elements what size and placement to draw.  Here is [one such example](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/).